# How to get direction of place wherever we touch in map from current location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I went through lots of links but I am getting confuse about getting direction on Google map.
When my apps get start it shows user's current location, and when user click on hospital logo which is on map, it will shows all hospitals within 5 km with user's current location. When user click on any places hospital he get information about it.
Now my point is I want to show direction from current location to hospital which is touched by user.
I am using google map `API of v2`.
Please give me the way through which I can achieve this task...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
try {
        Intent directioIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + strSourceLatitude  + "," + strSourceLongitude + "&daddr=" + strDestinationLatitude + "," + strDestinationLongitude));
            directioIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(directioIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utilities.showToast(GetDirectionActivity.this, "Google Map is not installed on your device.");
        }
```

Comment: :but I want to show direction on same map-view where I shows nearby hospitals and current location.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this blog post I wrote on painting a `Polyline` on `Google Maps API V2` to draw direction from one location to another:

[Google Maps API V2 Directions](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

you will find the the relevant methods to get you started.